# use custom interpreter

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I wrote an interpreter for cpp.
how can I use it in ros and write my code for this interpreter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288670/use-custom-interpreter/) by [ashkan_abd](https://answers.ros.org/users/34638/ashkan_abd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you mean that you wrote a compiler for C++, since C++ is not an interpreted language.

ROS uses whatever compiler the environment says is the current one. How to change the compiler for your environment (which can be done on a shell-by-shell basis, or system wide) is not really ROS specific, but it's also easy enough to do. Set the `CC` environment variable to the compiler's executable to change the C compiler, and the `CXX` environment variable to change the C++ compiler. If you are using CMake (which you are for ROS) then you can also do it in a CMakeLists.txt file by setting the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variables to the path to the compiler executable. I'm not sure how much Catkin will like having this variable changed in one package, though. It might take effect for the whole workspace, or it might just be overridden.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashkan_abd](https://answers.ros.org/users/34638/ashkan_abd/) on 2018-04-16**:
please say more details how can do this?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-04-17**:
Setting environment variables is a basic Linux question. I suggest you [read up on how to use the shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), and if you have any further Linux-related questions, ask them at a [Linux help site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).